# Linked List Appcrash

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to do an example about linked list. First, I added the values to the variables and there was no problem. But when I tried to get values from user, the program crashed when entering midterm 2 grade. I tried other input functions but the result is same. Where is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct student 
  {
         char *name;
         int m1,m2,final;
         struct student* next;
  };

main()
{
  addStudent();
  system("PAUSE");
}
addStudent()
{
  struct student *node = NULL;
  struct student *firstnode;
  firstnode = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
  node = firstnode;
  printf("press 0 to exit \n");
  while(1)
  {
    printf("Student name: ");
    scanf("%s", node->name)
    if(node->name == "0") break;
    printf("Midterm 1: ");
    scanf("%d", node->m1);
    printf("Midterm 2: ");
    scanf("%d", node->m2); 
    printf("Final: ");
    scanf("%d", node->final); 
    node->next = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    node = node->next;
  }
  node->next = NULL;
  node = firstnode;
  while(node->next);
 while(node->next != NULL)
 {
   printf("%s -  ",node->name);
   printf("%d   ", node->m1);
   printf("%d   ", node->m2);
   printf("%d   ", node->final);
   node = node->next;
 }
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix 1

Remove the line

```
while(node->next);
```

**Reason:** It will put you on an infinite loop in most cases and it is unnecessary.

---

### Fix 2

Replace the loop

```
while(node->next != NULL) {

}
```

with

```
if (node->next != NULL) {
    while (node->next->next != NULL) {

    }
}
```

**Reason:** You are allocating one additional struct each time and keeping it empty for reading next time. So the Linked List will end before the next becomes NULL.

---

### Fix 3

Replace following in struct

```
char *name;
```

with

```
char name[80];
```

**Reason:** Memory not being allocated.

---

### Fix 4

Replace at all occurrences of `scanf` (except for `name`)

```
scanf("%d", node->m1);
```

with

```
scanf("%d", &node->m1);
```

**Reason:** `scanf` needs memory location of data to be read.

Good luck

Comment: thansk. i fixed them but main issue still exist

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors.

To start with, the first `scanf("%s", node->name)` is missing its terminating semicolon.

Next, your function signatures are sloppy.  `main()` should be `int main(void)`.  `addStudent()` should be `int addStudent(void)`.  (Or, get rid of its `return 0` and let it return `void`.)  Since you don't pre-declare `addStudent()`, you should define it before `main()` so that `main()` can know about it.

The crash, though, is because you haven't allocated memory for `node->name`.  You've allocated memory for a `node`, but that doesn't give you space to put the name.

Comment: thanks for helping. i know there are many error. i will fix them later. so, how can i allocate memory for a node?